# PHP: Text Area echo in form won't echo during validation

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea, echo

Currently I have a form that goes through validation, and echo statement that are entered and returned errors on what needs to be filled in. My commenting area is within a  tag. It throws the error when it's empty. But when it's filled and other areas are empty, it DOES NOT echo the previously entered text.

I view another question that claims to have an answer. Previous I was using:`<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>` in my value result. The "answer" said to replace value with and htmlentities() as such: `<?php echo htmlentities($comments, ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);?>` However, that did not work either.

I want the comments  to echo, when text is entered, but other areas still need info.

HTML form text area:

```
<textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="10" placeholder="Please enter your comments here..." value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['comments'], ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);?>"></textarea>
```

PHP (not sure if needed here in this answer):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
$POST = filter_post($_POST);
$invoice = array_splice($POST,3,1);
$MSG = check_empty($POST);
if(!array_filter($MSG)){
    $POST['invoice'] = $invoice['invoice'];
    if(send_mail($POST)){
        $MSG[] = "Email Success";
    }
    else{
        $MSG[] = "Email Failed";
    }
}
}
function filter_post($POST){
$keys = array('name','phone','email','invoice','comments');
$POST = array_intersect_key($POST, array_flip($keys));
$POST = array_map('strip_tags', $POST);
return($POST);
}
function check_empty($POST){
foreach($POST as $key => $value){
    if(empty($value)){
        $MSG[] = "You need to fill out the $key section";
    }
}
return($MSG);
}
function send_mail($POST){
extract($POST);
$to = 'jordan@jordandavis.work';
$sbj = 'New Question For Se7en Service!';
$msg = "Name: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Invoice #: $invoice \n Comments: $comments";
$headers = "From: $email";
return(mail($to, $sbj, $msg, $headers));
}
function output_errors($MSG){
return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $MSG) . '</li></ul>';  
}
?>
```

[Link to question with answer that didn't work for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630161/echo-doesnt-show-copy-pasted-text-from-txt-file-to-form-text-area-php)

Comment: `<textarea>` does not have a `value` attribute. see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7 The `value` goes between the tags -> `<textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="10" placeholder="Please enter your comments here..."><?php echo htmlentities($_POST['comments'], ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);?></textarea>`

Comment: Perfect my man. Thank You! Did not know <textarea> tag didn't have a value attribute. Appreciate it!

Comment: Sean, make this an answer instead of a comment so I can vote it correctly.

Comment: added it as an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32196648/689579

Comment: THANKS. Wanted to give you the credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<textarea>` element does not have a `value` attribute. The 'value' is set between the opening/closing tags ->

```
<textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="10" placeholder="Please enter your comments here...">
    <?php echo htmlentities($_POST['comments'], ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);?>
</textarea>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7
or
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
 <textarea><?=$your_value?></textarea>
```

instead of

```
<textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" rows="10" cols="10" placeholder="Please enter your comments here..." value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['comments'], ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);?>"></textarea>
```

Comment: textarea does not have `value` attribute and using short tags is bad practice.

Comment: Didn't was to make an additional <textarea>, to be honest did not test, Sean above's answer worked. Thank you for the response.